# Removing background-color on nav-pills

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay, so I know nav-pills is deprecated in bootstrap's latest version. But, I'm having an issue changing the link's background-color on hover/focus. I thin it's a DOM related issue, but I have tried every angle. Would appreciate any help.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- sm/md  -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- lg -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
                <li class="cloud-offset">
                    <a href="#"><img src="homecloud.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="aboutcloud.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><img src="projectscloud.png"></a>
                </li>
                <li class="cloud-offset">
                    <a href="#"><img src="contactcloud.png"></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Here's what I have currently:-

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
background-color: transparent;}
```

Thanks in advance and let me know if any further info is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your css example this:

```
    .navbar-default .nav-pills > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .nav-pills > li > a:focus {
    background-color: transparent !important;}
```

for remove background-color of a tag's

Comment: Thanks Jorge, that did the trick!

It was the !important I was missing.